# GitKraken error - clone failed - early EOF fatal fetch-pack invalid index-pack output

Tags: git, gitkraken

Anyone know the reason for this GitKraken error I am getting?  It started happening out of nowhere, and is intermittent.  The clone sometimes works, sometimes fails.  The remote end is GitHub.

[image]

(GitKraken support is asking me to try things that I do not feel are related to the issue.)  Thanks.

Comment: Any way you can get the rest of that second message? This looks like a timeout, but the missing text would be useful for confirming that.

Comment: @JimRedmond Would it be in a log file that GitKraken keeps?  BTW I never face this issue when using official Git's bash shell.